# Return a particular whole row from data frame if value falls in the range

Tags: r

```
names   1day  2day
 ab       20    6
 bc       30    3
 cd       40    10
 ef       15    8
```

1. Using which condition how to return the the highest 2 scores on 2day
2. Using which condition how to return the rows which are between 4 and 9 on 2day.

If possible, could you show the code in IF condition and in while condition as well?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `subset`

```
subset(df1, `2day` == max(`2day`))
```

For the second case

```
subset(df1,  `2day` %in% 4:9)
```

If this doesn't include 4 and 9

```
subset(df1, `2day` %in% 5:8)
```

---

If we need to get the highest two scores

```
head(df1[order(df1$`2day`, decreasing = TRUE),], 2)
```

Comment: HI, could you show the code for highest 2 scores in c.

like in the above ex.  2 highest are 10 and 8.
so the o/p should be 
 cd       40    10
 ef       15    8 

------------------------
if possible, please write the code using while and If conditions

Comment: @chaitanyayatam  Updated the post